# Using mail to with parameters

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

is it possible to set the address of a mailto to the selected value of a drop down list?

Something like: param1 = dropdownlist1.selectedvalue

```
    <a href=”mailto:param1?subject=mail from server”>Send Email</a>
```

I can't think of how to get the param1 to work on an .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send on single click 
then you have to work like this

```
<a href=”mailto:'<%=string.format("param1")%>'?subject=mail”>Send Email</a>
```

typo error may there.

Comment: What I have is a dropdown list of all the members in my web application, then I want a “sent to” link when I click on the “send to” it opens an email addressed to the selected member from the dropdown list. This is on an intranet and only people from our company can see.

Comment: k. then same.. 
as u said 'param1 = dropdownlist1.selectedvalue'

then use  '<a href=”mailto:'<%=string.format("param1")%>'?subject=mail”>Send Email</a>'